# Each UITableViewCell play different sound

Tags: ios

I am working on a recorder which which has a UITableView and my records would be saved in NSDOcumenDirectory the problem is that i want when user touches each cell it plays the recordFile which was selected. How should i fill the DidSelectRowAtIndex part and i dont want to use switch because its for limited datas i want a way for unlimited datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something a switch-case method like below in your didselectrowatindex method:

```
switch(indexpath.row)
{
     case 1:
          // Code to Play sound 1
          break;

     case 2:
           // Code to Play sound 2
          break;

     ...
     case value N:
           // Code to Play sound N
          // Program statement
          ...
          break;

     default:
           // Code to Play default (if present)
          // Program statement
          ...
          break;
}
```